# Spring data JPA/hibernate query over java.util.Map keys?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data

i am building an application that is localized. There are 4 entities using this localizable system and i have used java.util.Maps for this, for example:

```
public class ProductDAO extends AbstractDAO {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2036153197095739149L;

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "lang")
    @Column(name = "title")
    @CollectionTable(name = "product_title", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"), indexes = @Index(columnList = "lang", unique = true))
    private Map<String, String> title;

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "lang")
    @Column(name = "description")
    @CollectionTable(name = "product_description", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"), indexes = @Index(columnList = "lang", unique = true))
    private Map<String, String> description;

    @CollectionTable(name = "topics")
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<String> topics;
    private float price;
}
```

How can a generate a query in spring (pretty sure i cant use an auto-generated, ill have to use @Query) that gives me the entity with a specific localization? For example i have this projection of this class:

```
public class ProductProjection {

    private String title;
    private String description;
    private Set<String> topics;
    private float price;
}
```

My goal is given the id (in the AbstractDAO extension in the first class) and the language for example english i can make the query work:

```
@Query("some query i have no idea how to make here")
Optional<ProductProjection> findByIdAndLanguage(String id, String lang);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if there is any interest but i developed a solution:

```
@Query("select new com.example.demo.ProductProj(p.id, p.version, p.price, VALUE(l).name, VALUE(l).description) from Product p join p.localizations as l where (VALUE(l).name) like %:name% and (KEY(l)) = :lang")
```

Basically puts the basic product stull in the projection, then adds the value(l)'s properties when the query matches. You should query the keys so that you ensure there is only one value. If you need more values you can pass Value(l) directly as a collection