# Select using JPA Query Element Collection which is Map

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an issue, because our setup assumes properties in one entity. I want to query that properties and check if there is property key with a certain value. And if that is so, I would return the object.
Here below there is pseudocode of that solution with that field which is interesting to me.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some")
class Some {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Convert(converter = ConverterToJson.class, attributeName = "value")
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "some_properties", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "object_id"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "property_key")
    @Column(length = 4000)
    private Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    
    
}
```

From that structure I want to do some query like:

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT so FROM Some so JOIN so.properties prop WHERE prop.key = 'searchedKey' AND prop.value = :searchedValue")
    Set<Some> findAllBySearchedKeyEqual(@Param("searchedKey") Long searchedValue);
```

I've tried this above, of course it is not valid query. Does anybody know how to do that query properly?

EDIT

After some more research I've found out that you should use method VALUE() and KEY() but now the issue is that there is nested select which returns multiple results.

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT so FROM Some so INNER JOIN so.properties prop " +
            "WHERE ((KEY(prop)) = 'searchedKey' AND (VALUE(prop)) = ':searchedValue')")
    Set<Some> findAllBySearchedKeyEqual(@Param("searchedKey") Long searchedValue);
```

I've used some of this answer: [Spring data JPA/hibernate query over java.util.Map keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67855284/spring-data-jpa-hibernate-query-over-java-util-map-keys)

Comment: Your JOIN needs an ON.

Comment: Does your Some table have a so column? If you want _all_ its columns, do SELECT so.*.

Comment: *of course it is not valid query* any error messaeg

Comment: @jarlh that is jpql nit sql in this case on is not needed

Comment: @Jens, so the <sql> tag isn't related to the question?

Comment: @jarlh I do not think so

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: cannot dereference scalar collection element: key

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is more of a **design problem** or a **bad practice** than a program error. That is why there is no easy/appropriate way to fetch the data you need. You almost never want a hashmap object inside an entity. A better practice would be to create another entity called `SomeProperties` and link all properties of a `Some` object with `SomeProperties` instances.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some")
class Some {

    @Id
    private Long some_id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="some")
    private Set<SomeProperties> properties = new ArrayList<>(); 
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "some_properties")
class SomeProperties {

    @Id
    private Long property_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="some_id", nullable=false)
    private Some some;

    @Column(value = "key")
    private String key;

    @Column(value = "value")
    private Long value;
}
```

This way, you can manage your Some and its properties in a safer and more convenient manner.

Also, you have an error in your query method. You pass one parameter only but you need to pass both the key and value to match. Your query will look like the following.

At your `Some` repository:

```
@Query("select s from Some s inner join s.properties p where p.key = :key and p.value = :value")
Set<Some> findAllByKeyAndValueEqual(@Param("key") String key, @Param("value") Long value);
```